# Increment number input with rules to steps

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create number input with counting rules, for example, I want to have first 5 increment steps to be 100 units (100 - 500) and once reaching 500 change increment steps to `500`.

So it will be `100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000...`

Here is what I have tried so far, something causes the 500 step attribute trigger only when reaching 600 instead 500.

```js
$('input#grams_quantity').on( "change", function(){
    console.log('works');
    if($(this).val() > 400){
        $("#grams_quantity").attr('step', 500);
        console.log('500');
    } else {
        $("#grams_quantity").attr('step', 100);
        console.log('100');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" step="100" name="grams_quantity" class="grams_quantity" id="grams_quantity" value="100" min="100">
```

How can I set rules to number input increment steps correctly?

Comment: After some testing I realized that, although it does not produce an Error, changing the `step` changes the `box-shadow` to red when you do in on an Event. Therefore it's really seen as an error. Use a separate Element for the other step. I would just hide and show the Elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to get the wanted values, because the change happens before the event is called and then it needs to take action for the next click.

1. Why does not simply changing the increment to `500` work?

   Because of the `min` value and a multiple of `500`. By having `min="100"` and `step="500"`, the next reachable value is `600`.

   Solution: Change both values, `min="0"` and `step="500"`.
2. Why do wee need another condition? Why not simply check the value `500` for turning back to `step="100"`?

   - Solution for values greater than `500`:

     - Adjust start to zero and step to `500`.
     - Adjust `value` to at least `1000`.
   - Solution for values smaller or equal than `500`.

     - Adjust start to `100` and step to `500`.
   - You need to cover user inputs as well and adust the values

---

EDIT: Added `last` in a closure for distinguish between arrow changing values and hand input values.

For example take an direct input of `600`, this value is rounded to `500`, but if the value is reached by up arrow pressing, you get `1000`.

```js
$('input#grams_quantity').on("change", function (last) {
    return function() {
        if (+$(this).val() > 500) {
            $("#grams_quantity").attr('step', 500);
            $("#grams_quantity").attr('min', 0);
            this.value = last === 500 && +this.value === 600
                ? 1000
                : Math.round(this.value / 500) * 500;
        } else {
            $("#grams_quantity").attr('step', 100);
            $("#grams_quantity").attr('min', 100);
            this.value = Math.max(100, Math.round(this.value / 100) * 100);
        }
        last = +this.value;
    };
}(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="100" name="grams_quantity" class="grams_quantity" id="grams_quantity" value="100" min="100">
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, try go to 1000, lower back down to 400 and go back up, it will create problem and values like `600` or `700` will appear. How can I solve that?